# conditional merging of different ID by another condition

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to do conditional merging. I have two datasets `a` and `b` and I want to merge them to get dataset `D`. The problem is that the ID of the two datasets do not match but they are on same date and time. How can I do this?

```
X=c("A","B")
S=c("p", "A")
ID= c(1234,2456)
date=c("23/1/2017 9:00","23/1/2017 9:00 ")
a=data.frame(cbind(X,S,ID,date))
X=c("A","B")
C=c(10, 200)
ID= c(1234,1234)
b=data.frame(cbind(X,C,ID))

X=c("A","B")
S=c("p", "A")
ID= c(1234,2456)
date=c("23/1/2017 9:00","23/1/2017 9:00 ")
C=c(10, 200)
D=data.frame(cbind(X,S,ID,date, C))
```

Comment: On which condition do you want to merge? Are you aware, that the date column is not identical (there is an additional space in the second value). Do you want to keep the first ID of the day and merge on that or how?

Comment: Thank you for the time. I have edited the question by adding variable in dataset b. Now i want to merge a and b having different ids to get like D data set by any condition. Is this fine

Comment: Do you want to have this: `merge(a, b[, -3], by = "X")`?

Comment: in principal yes but the ids are not the same therefore i cant get dataset D. therefore can we implement condition that include date time and say when time is same consider the ids of A and B od dataset a as equal and merge with dataset b. I know its confusing to understand i am sorry for that